# Setting Username and Password to Windows VM from GCP deployment manager with Jinja2

Tags: google-cloud-platform, jinja2, google-deployment-manager

I am new to GCP and trying to create a Windows VM instance from GCP deployment manager.

I want to set username and password for the VM instance through deployment manager. Here I am using Jinja2 as deployment language.

Comment: I was able to find a [documentation](https://cloud.google.com/deployment-manager/docs/configuration/templates/create-basic-template) that might be helpful

Answer (score 0, accepted):

GCP does not set the username and passwords on GCP. The best way to get a user and password set at VM creation is through the use of [metadata startup scripts](https://cloud.google.com/compute/docs/startupscript)

Since you just want to create the user, you will likely want to use the `sysprep-specialize-script-ps1` field so that the command only runs on creation (not on every startup). For the value, write a powershell script that will create a user add it to the appropriate group (likely administrators)
Here is an example:

```
sysprep-specialize-script-ps1 = "$Password = ConvertTo-SecureString -String {{ password }} -AsPlainText -Force\n\nNew-LocalUser -name {{ user }} -Password $Password\n\nAdd-LocalGroupMember -Group Administrators -Member {{ user }}"
```